# Express.js ignore SyntaxError in case of unknown route

Tags: node.js, api, express, error-handling

In the express app below:

- Executing a POST for /push with invalid json data will cause an HTTP 400 error to be sent back to the client
- Executing a POST with valid json data, but for an unknown route will cause an HTTP 404 error to be sent back to the client
- Executing a POST with invalid json data for an unknown route, will cause an HTTP 400 error to be sent back to the client

What I'd like to achieve, is that in the third scenario, also the 404 would be sent. In other words, in case the route is unknown, I want that to be catched by app.post('*',(req, res, next)), which will throw the 404, and not by the generic middleware error handler, which throws a 400 json SyntaxError

Any way to achieve this?

```
const express = require('express');
const { handleError, ErrorHandler } = require('./helpers/error');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.data);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.post('/push', function(req, res){
    console.log('push API');
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.post('*',(req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Unknown route');
    throw new ErrorHandler(404, 'API endpoint does not exist.');
   });

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Middleware error handling');
    handleError(err, res);
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server started on port 3000')
});
```

error.js content:

```
class ErrorHandler extends Error {
    constructor(statusCode, message) {
      super();
      this.statusCode = statusCode;
      this.message = message;
    }
  }

const handleError = (err, res) => {
    const { statusCode, message } = err;
    res.status(statusCode).json({
      status: "error",
      statusCode,
      message
    });
};

module.exports = {
    ErrorHandler,
    handleError
}
```

Comment: Please the contents of handleErorr and ErrorHandler .

Comment: Updated to add content of helpers/error.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By sending a request to a non-existing route, none of your handlers are matched. Thus, your error handling middleware

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Middleware error handling');
    handleError(err, res);
});
```

is executed directly. What you can do is to try to detect a Syntax/parsing error in your `handleError` function. Something like:

```
const handleError = (err, res) => {
    let {statusCode, message} = err;

    if (err.status === 400 && err.message.includes("Unexpected token")) {
        statusCode = 404;
    }

    res.status(statusCode).json({
        status: "error",
        statusCode,
        message
    });
};
```

EDIT:

The issue can be fixed by only using the json-parser middleware for the routes you want to parse json and removing it as a general middleware for all requests:

```
...
//app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.post('/', express.json(), function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.data);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.post('/push', express.json(), function (req, res) {
    console.log('push API');
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if a SyntaxErro occurs for an existing route? How can I make the distinction between SyntaxErro for existing route (needs to generate HTTP 400) and SyntaxError for non-exsting route (needs to generate HTTP 404). I belive with the code above, all the SyntaxErros with message "unexpected token" will generate an HTTP 404, even for existing routes? Please correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: Thanks, maybe another way to describe it in a more generic way: I have two error codes, HTTP 400 for SyntaxError, and HTTP 404 for non-existing route. In case a SyntaxError occurs for non-existing route, I want to give 'priority' to the HTTP 404 and send that to client.

Comment: I've edited my answer and I think it should work now, but I'm not entirely happy with the solution. Maybe I'll come up with something better.

Comment: Did it work for you? You need to remove my first suggestion with checking the status/message in your handler. Just move your `expres.json()` middleware to the route-handlers where you want to process json.

Comment: It works, Just thought there perhaps would have been a more generic approach to it, rather than adding express.json() explicitly to each route. For what I need though, it will do. Thanks, much appreciated.